# How to check the groups a person joined?

Tags: java, arrays

I have 3 String arrays. How to check the groups a person joined?

```
String[] groupA = new String {"Tom", "Chris", "Jack", "Mary"};
String[] groupB = new String {"Chris", "Peter", "Jimmy"};
String[] groupC = new String {"Chris", "Paul", "Michael", "Jack"};
```

Comment: Use `HashSet` or `ArrayList`.

Comment: Did you already write any code? Show your effort if so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First convert the `Array` into a `List`. Then check using `contains` method.

```
boolean joinedA = Arrays.asList(groupA).contains(name);
boolean joinedB = Arrays.asList(groupB).contains(name);
boolean joinedC = Arrays.asList(groupC).contains(name);
```